# Dynamically setting function and parameters through objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

Below I have code which executes depending on the value of `Card`. For example if `Card` is `recruitCarpenter` then the function executed should be `recruitCarpenter()` and it needs to have the parameters `G, ctx.currentPlayer`, so `recruitCarpenter(G, ctx.currentPlayer)`

Hover a function such as `shipBallista()` needs 4 parameters rather than just those two: `G, ctx.currentPlayer, G.opponent, G.attackMultiplier`.

Code is shown below:

```js
let cardCost = {wood: 0, gunpowder:0, gold: 0, fleet: 0};
let cardFunction = {function: ""};

identifyCard(G, ctx, card, cardCost, cardFunction);

cardFunction.function(); //NEED THE CORRECT PARAMETERS HERE  

function identifyCard(G, ctx, card, cardCost, cardFunction) {
    switch (card) {
        //WOOD CARDS
        case "recruitCarpenter" :
            cardCost.wood = 8;
            cardFunction.function = recruitCarpenter;
            //Requires 'G, ctx.currentPlayer' as parameters
        break;
        case "shipBallista" : 
            cardCost.wood = 12;
            cardFunction.function = shipBallista;
             //Requires 'G, ctx.currentPlayer, G.opponent, G.attackMuliplier' as parameters
        break;
    }
}
```

How can I have function as intended with changing functions and parameters.

I have tried this, however it did not work:

Define parameters:  `let cardFunctionParameters = {parameters: ""};`

Update parameters: `cardFunctionParameters.parameters = G, ctx.currentPlayer;`

Execute function with parameters: `cardFunction.function(cardFunctionParameters.parameters);`

Snippet shows it all together:

```js
let cardCost = {wood: 0, gunpowder:0, gold: 0, fleet: 0};
let cardFunction = {function: ""};
let cardFunctionParameters = {parameters: ""};

identifyCard(G, ctx, card, cardCost, cardFunction, cardFunctionParameters);

cardFunction.function(cardFunctionParameters.parameters); //Doesn't work gives error: Cannot read properties of undefined     

function identifyCard(G, ctx, card, cardCost, cardFunction, cardFunctionParameters) {
    switch (card) {
        //WOOD CARDS
        case "recruitCarpenter" :
            cardCost.wood = 8;
            cardFunction.function = recruitCarpenter;
            cardFunctionParameters.parameters = G, ctx.currentPlayer;
        break;
        case "shipBallista" : 
            cardCost.wood = 12;
            cardFunction.function = shipBallista;
            cardFunctionParameters.parameters = G, ctx.currentPlayer, G.opponent, G.attackMultiplier;
        break;
    }
}
```

Maybe what's wrong is that it doesn't like me setting an object value to `G, ctx.currentPlayer` (so with the comma), however if I send it as an array [G, ctx.currentPlayer], how would I have the `cardFunction.function(cardFunctionParameters.parameters[0],cardFunctionParameters.parameters[1]);` work for varying array lengths.

Comment: Just pass all the parameters. The function can then take care to use the ones it actually needs.

Comment: @VLAZ can you give me an example please

Comment: `someFunction(param1, param2, param3, param4)` where `someFunction` is dynamic. So if it's `someFunction = foo` then the implementation might be `foo = (p1, p2) => p1 + p2` (using just the first two parameters). While another implementation might do something different: `bar = (p1, p2, p3, p4) => \`${p3} is ${p4} and costs ${p1 * p2}\``, so when `someFunction = bar`, you get different behaviour and you don't need to alter how you call `someFunction` itself. It's also better to pass a single object with all the parameters in it, so the functions can more easily pick out what's needed.

Comment: I understand what you mean @VLAZ. What do you suggest for me to do with the following situation. Let's say I am having the `someFunction(param1, param2, param3, param4)`. But then `foo` function uses only `param1, param2` while `bar` uses `param1, param3`. Would I still include `param2` for `bar` but never use it? Or is there another way?

Comment: Pass a a parameter object. Then you'd have `foo = param => param.p1 + param.p2` and then `bar = param => param.p3 * param.p4`. As I said, it's easier to pick out what's needed.

Comment: @VLAZ How can that be written in non-arrow function as I am not too confident with those. Can it be done without `=>`

Comment: `function foo(param) { return param.p1 + param.p2; }` which you'd call with something like `foo({ p1: 12, p2: 40, p3: 7, p4: 14})` or whatever values you want.